# ir transmitter and receiver raspberry pi false edge detection

Tags: raspbian

first time posting here so i will try to explain my best .
I have 1 infra red transmitter on one side and second on other side , and when someone passes through i want to detect and call some function.
Everything is working fine , but sometimes it detects passing through when nobody is passed , something like false edge detection, plus when i cross and stand in between the calling function is called 3 times or 2 times , depends. I dont know what the problem may be , i tried connecting it like this [LINK](https://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges)

without the capacitor but its still the same , My code is :

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

pin = 11

def on_pushdown(channel):

    latest_state = None
    inputValue = gpio.input(pin)
    if inputValue != latest_state:
        latest_state = inputValue
        if latest_state:
            print("Button2 pressed")



try:
    # Setting GPIO layout
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    # Set pin as input pin pulled down to GND
    gpio.setup(pin, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
    gpio.setup(pin1, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_UP)




    while True:
        #print(gpio.input(11))
        if not 'event' in locals():
            event = gpio.add_event_detect(pin, gpio.FALLING, callback=on_pushdown, bouncetime=1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

finally:
    gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: your LINK seems broken.

Comment: now its working

Comment: thank you, working now. But the link is about how to use GPIO edge trigger interrupt, nothing to do with infra read transmitter and receiver.  Did I miss any thing? The tutorial is 5 years ago, therefore might not be updated. I would recommend to use the most up to date GPIO or GPIO.Zero modules. Perhaps try these: (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/python/README.md, (2) https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Comment: I could no longer find the official GPIO module. I can only find the GPIO.Zero. Just now Icascually google and find this tutorial covering both GPIO and GPIO.Zero. ro. Just now I casually googled and found this tutorial covering both GPIO and GPIO.Zero. But I have not read it thoroughly. "Control Raspberry Pi GPIO Pins from Python" - Jeff Tranter 2019jul31.
https://www.ics.com/blog/control-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-python

Comment: Not sure how is the capacitor used in your IR circuit. Is it used for the button, connected to IR transmitter transistor? I think you can try and error a higher value, up to 1uF.

Comment: How long are the wires between the sensors and the Pi?

Comment: I will try to answer all of your question starting from the top :
Yeah i know that is an old post but the idea is the same , i think my problem is the uncotinious (not constant XD) power , so even the smallest changes in the power are detected , and as far as i know , the capacitor has something to do with the stabillizing the power.

Comment: I did not try the other libraries because they are simillar and in my situation i think i will stay with the Rpi.gpio for now

Comment: I did not connected the capacitor because i am not sure how to implement it in my circuit ,  because i have , ground from IR to gnd to raspberry and pusle from IR to pin11 on raspberry

Comment: The wires are  around 10 m long

Comment: From the circuit in the link i just connected the resistors

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution , so if somebody come across this post , and its in simillar situation like me , because there are a lot of people with the same problem here is link to the solution:

[LINK](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=134394&p=896208#p896208)

Comment: Please don't just post a link-only answer. Explain in short the solution and take the link only as reference. And please accept your own answer after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Hi @Raspu, Ah, the link you recommend about edge interrupt is very good for me ninja grade edge interrupt lovers/haters.  I have perhaps read 500+ posts in that forum's troubleshooting and also sensors and automation projects section and I would rank it top 0.1%. For those who have not yet followed the link, I would repeat the addr here, and then give my comments, perhaps after others. "Avoiding False Hits with RPi.GPIO Edge Detection (19 posts, 30+ min read) - apulv rpi.org.forums.troubleshooting 2016jan29":
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=134394. Cheers.